# RegionMember command alternative that can check members exactly?

Tags: regions, precision-and-accuracy, polygons

My problem is as follows:

I have an exact rational polygon created using `ConvexHullMesh` and given a rational point I need Mathematica to decide exactly if it is inside the polygon or not. I feel like this should be possible to implement. RegionMember seeemingly works and doesn't work depending how it is implemented. Let's consider a toy case:

`ConvexHullMesh[{{-1,1},{1,1},{1,-1},{-1,-1}}]` This is of course a square and checking polygon coordinates we can see that Mathematica treats this exactly:

`PolygonCoordinates[ConvexHullMesh[{{-1, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, -1}, {-1, -1}}]]`

gives

`{{-1, -1}, {-1, 1}, {1, -1}, {1, 1}}`

Originally I hoped that RegionMember might work, but it does not. Looking at the documentation we can see that it treats the point you are testing numerically, and not exactly.Thus

`RegionMember[ConvexHullMesh[{{-1, 1}, {-1, -1}, {1, -1}, {1, 1}}], {1+1/10000000000000, 1}]` returns `True` which is false. Is there anything I co do so Mathematica checks it exactly?

One Idea I had was instead of making it a region, make it a polygon. Oddly enough `RegionMember[Polygon[{{-1, 1}, {-1, -1}, {1, -1}, {1, 1}}], {1 +1/10000000000000,1}]` returns `False`. Which is great but I am not sure why this worked and the other one did not, It seems it should treat the point numerically in both cases.

In any case, if making it a polygon works, which I am not sure if it does. I could simply consider `RegionMember[Polygon@PolygonCoordinates@ConvexHullMesh[{{-1, 1}, {-1, -1}, {1, -1}, {1, 1}}],{1 +1/10000000000000,1}]` However, not only does this seem roundabout, it also does not always work. `Polygon` cares about the order of points, so I would need to order polygon coordinates appropriately which I do not know how to do.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`RegionWithin[region, Point @ pt]`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionWithin.html):

```
RegionWithin[ConvexHullMesh[{{-1, 1}, {-1, -1}, {1, -1}, {1, 1}}], 
 Point @ {1 + 1/10000000000000, 1}]
```

> ```
> False
> ```

```
RegionWithin[ConvexHullMesh[{{-1, 1}, {-1, -1}, {1, -1}, {1, 1}}], 
 Point@{1, 1}]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Alternatively, use [`SignedRegionDistance`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SignedRegionDistance.html):

```
SignedRegionDistance[ConvexHullMesh[{{-1, 1}, {-1, -1}, {1, -1}, {1, 1}}],
    {1 + 1/10000000000000, 1}] <= 0.
```

> ```
> False
> ```

```
SignedRegionDistance[ConvexHullMesh[{{-1, 1}, {-1, -1}, {1, -1}, {1, 1}}],
     {1, 1}] <= 0.
```

> ```
> True
> ```